# Date Time Picker jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to implement a date time picker. It works with the first function where you can't pick an end date before a start date. But when I add a function for setting the date format the whole thing stops working. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/     javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
rel="Stylesheet"type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$("#txtFrom").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
          onSelect: function (selected) {
            var dt = new Date(selected);
            dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
            $("#txtTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
        }
   });
   $("#txtTo").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function (selected) {
        var dt = new Date(selected);
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
        $("#txtFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
    }
    });
$.validator.methods.date = function(value, element) { 
  return this.optional(element) || Date.parseExact(value, "dd-MM-yyyy"); 
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by console errors.

Comment: Check the developer console: [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console), [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console)

Comment: Are you loading jQuery validator? I don't see the script reference in there and $.validator would be undefined.

Comment: How do I load jQuery validator?

Comment: Assuming this is the plugin you are looking for? [jQuery validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what may be your `$.validator.methods.date`...

So try jQuery UI date format option instead:

```
$("#txtFrom").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});

$("#txtFrom").on("change",function(){
    var dt = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+1); 
    $("#txtTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
});

$("#txtTo").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});

$("#txtTo").on("change",function(){
    var dt = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate()-1);
    $("#txtFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
});
```

[Working Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/h9k6b15g/)

**Note:** I used other CDNs for the libraries used in this fiddle...
It needed some with `https://`.

Comment: I updated my answer... Because I noticed that the +1d or -1d wasn't working... This one is working like you wish. ;)